# Extract data from a nested list and return a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, sapply, do.call

```
dput(head(z2,10))

structure(list(name = list("Mary"), department = structure(list(
    name = list("English")), .Names = "name", id = "300"), department = structure(list(
    name = list("Math")), .Names = "name", id = "301"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("Chinese")), .Names = "name", id = "302f"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("German")), .Names = "name", id = "302"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("German")), .Names = "name", id = "302f"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("Music")), .Names = "name", id = "303"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("Sport")), .Names = "name", id = "305"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("Chemistry")), .Names = "name", id = "306"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("Science")), .Names = "name", id = "308")), .Names = c("name", 
"department", "department", "department", "department", "department", "department", 
"department", "department", "department"))
```

I'm trying to extract information out of a list and put it into a data.frame, from [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079215/using-loop-to-extract-data-from-list-in-r/46081489), I just learned that you can use a `do.call` function to format it, I want to output it as a data frame.

Here's the code from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46079215/using-loop-to-extract-data-from-list-in-r/46081489#46081489) in that post:

```
c <- do.call(rbind,             
        lapply(unname(z2), 
               function(x) { 
                 temp <- unlist(x) 
                 data.frame(names(temp) == "name",
                            temp[names(temp) == "department.name"], 
                            unlist(sapply(x, attr, "id")), 
                            row.names=NULL) 
               }))
```

> Error in data.frame(names(temp) == "name", temp[names(temp) == "department.name"],  :
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0

---

new data:

```
structure(list(code = list("1"), note = list("success"), category = structure(list(
    name = list("Mary"), department = structure(list(name = list(
        "Math")), .Names = "name", id = "300"), department = structure(list(
        name = list("English")), .Names = "name", id = "301"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("Chinese")), .Names = "name", id = "302f"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("Music")), .Names = "name", id = "317")), .Names = c("name", 
"department", "department", "department", "department", "department", "department", 
"department", "department", "department", "department", "department", "department", 
"department", "department", "department")), category = structure(list(
    name = list("Kevin"), department = structure(list(name = list(
        "Physics")), .Names = "name", id = "12G0"), department = structure(list(
        name = list("German")), .Names = "name", id = "321"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("French")), .Names = "name", id = "325"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("Spanish")), .Names = "name", id = "427")), .Names = c("name", 
"department", "department", "department", "department", "department", "department", 
"department", "department", "department", "department")), category = structure(list(
    name = list("Andy"), department = structure(list(name = list(
        "Swedish")), .Names = "name", id = "330"), department = structure(list(
        name = list("Danish")), .Names = "name", id = "331"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("Russian")), .Names = "name", id = "332"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("Japanese")), .Names = "name", id = "341")), .Names = c("name", 
"department", "department", "department", "department", "department", "department", 
"department", "department", "department", "department", "department", "department", 
"department", "department", "department", "department", "department", "department", 
"department", "department", "department")), category = structure(list(
    name = list("Nana"), department = structure(list(name = list(
        "Arabic")), .Names = "name", id = "200"), department = structure(list(
        name = list("African")), .Names = "name", id = "201"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("Sport")), .Names = "name", id = "202"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("Korean")), .Names = "name", id = "211")), .Names = c("name", 
"department", "department", "department", "department", "department", "department", 
"department")), category = structure(list(name = list("Sandy"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("Vocals")), .Names = "name", id = "100"), 
    department = structure(list(name = list("Language")), .Names = "name", id = "515")), .Names = c("name", 
"department", "department", "department", "department", "department", "department", 
"department", "department", "department", "department", "department", "department"
))), .Names = c("code", "note", "category", "category", "category", 
"category", "category"))
```

Comment: the error tells you exactly what the problem is. No such name "department.name" in your temp list, so you've got zero rows for `temp[names(temp) == "department.name"]`

Comment: @waterling But I did have a department factor in my dput :o

Comment: The new data sample seems to be missing some closing brackets.

Comment: you should print `unlist (unname(z2)[[1]] ) ` to see what the structure of `temp` is. None of the elements have the name  'department.name'. If you are using rstudio, set breakpoints to stop and debug the code...

Comment: @Z.Lin relist it!

Comment: @waterling this information is really helpful! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited answer based on OP's new sample with nested lists, each representing one user (*modified* version of dataset reproduced below because there were more names than elements in each category, which didn't really make sense).

Data:

```
z2 <- structure(list(code = list("1"), 
                     note = list("success"), 
                     category = structure(list(name = list("Mary"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("Math")), .Names = "name", id = "300"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("English")), .Names = "name", id = "301"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("Chinese")), .Names = "name", id = "302f"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("Music")), .Names = "name", id = "317")), 
                                          .Names = c("name", "department", "department", "department", "department")), 
                     category = structure(list(name = list("Kevin"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("Physics")), .Names = "name", id = "12G0"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("German")), .Names = "name", id = "321"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("French")), .Names = "name", id = "325"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("Spanish")), .Names = "name", id = "427")), 
                                          .Names = c("name", "department", "department", "department", "department")), 
                     category = structure(list(name = list("Andy"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("Swedish")), .Names = "name", id = "330"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("Danish")), .Names = "name", id = "331"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("Russian")), .Names = "name", id = "332"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("Japanese")), .Names = "name", id = "341")), 
                                          .Names = c("name", "department", "department", "department", "department")), 
                     category = structure(list(name = list("Nana"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("Arabic")), .Names = "name", id = "200"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("African")), .Names = "name", id = "201"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("Sport")), .Names = "name", id = "202"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("Korean")), .Names = "name", id = "211")), 
                                          .Names = c("name", "department", "department", "department", "department")), 
                     category = structure(list(name = list("Sandy"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("Vocals")), .Names = "name", id = "100"), 
                                               department = structure(list(name = list("Language")), .Names = "name", id = "515")), 
                                          .Names = c("name", "department", "department"))), 
                .Names = c("code", "note", "category", "category", "category", "category", "category"))
```

Drop unneeded elements from the list:

```
# keep only category elements (i.e. drop code, note, etc. from the list)
z2 <- z2[which(names(z2)=="category")]
```

Convert each nested list into a data frame & bind them together:

```
do.call(rbind,
        lapply(unname(z2),
               function(y){
                 data.frame(
                   name = y[[which(names(y)=="name")]][[1]],
                   department = sapply(y[which(names(y)=="department")], function(x){x[[1]][[1]]}),
                   id = sapply(y[which(names(y)=="department")], function(x){attr(x, "id")})
                 )
               }))

    name department   id
1   Mary       Math  300
2   Mary    English  301
3   Mary    Chinese 302f
4   Mary      Music  317
5  Kevin    Physics 12G0
6  Kevin     German  321
7  Kevin     French  325
8  Kevin    Spanish  427
9   Andy    Swedish  330
10  Andy     Danish  331
11  Andy    Russian  332
12  Andy   Japanese  341
13  Nana     Arabic  200
14  Nana    African  201
15  Nana      Sport  202
16  Nana     Korean  211
17 Sandy     Vocals  100
18 Sandy   Language  515
```

Comment: This is just a part of my dput, so there's actually more users in this case. Is it possible to use it by do.call function? Since I want to learn how to construct it. Thanks!

Comment: @Ching Can you provide a sample dataset that includes multiple users?

Comment: Just list it! By the way, I parse it from a login website which is in xml format. So I don't need the code and note, just the category and its subset. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi! I have a third question, would you mind to give me some info about it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102697/extract-data-from-a-nested-list